# How to get the updated lines from text file in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

```
Receive-Job -Name updater >>C:\Users\d3\Documents\Batch\path\doc1.txt
clear-content "C:\Users\d3\Documents\Batch\path\doc1.txt"
```

The above code in the job may update multiple lines in the doc1. If doc1 gets updated, I need to retrieve the updated entries.

```
if(doc1 gets updated)
{
    get the updated entries alone in a variable
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?  I'm guessing that you will need your job to return the list of lines that were updated, since that would be a lot easier than trying to re-calculate what was modified after the fact.

Comment: Yeah..My job returns the list of lines that were updated, I need to email the updated lines . This whole code is in a loop. So unless I provide a condition, its difficult.

Comment: loop{ if(I get updates from receive-job or it updates doc1) { get the updated data send-email } }

Comment: I need something of similar kind 
 if([bool](Receive-Job -Name updater >>C:\Users\d3\Documents\Batch\path\doc1.txt)){Code}
But this doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

Your script is currently piping the output of the job blindly into `doc1`, and then trying to work out what that output was.  I'm not sure from your question whether you actually *need* `doc1` or whether you're just trying to use that to capture the output.

Instead of that, simply capturing the result first, so you can work with it:

```
$lines = Receive-Job -Name updater
if ($lines.Count -ne 0)
{
    # send your email here if there are lines returned

    # push the output to the file, if you still need to
    $lines >> C:\Users\d3\Documents\Batch\path\doc1.txt
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to capture the output in doc1 and attach it to the mail I want to send.The "if condition" you've provided turns to be true even when Receive-job doesn't have new entries.So, if(doc gets updated){send email, clear doc} is what i'm looking for

Comment: If you always have lines in your job's output, the file will always be updated.  When `Receive-job` doesn't have new entries, what's the content of `$lines`?